# foreach to cast objects in php

Tags: php, foreach, casting, pass-by-reference

Let say i have a cast function,

```
Object::cast($stdClass, 'MyClass');
```

this function works perfectly, however when I use this foreach loop,

```
foreach ($stdClasses as &$stdClass) { // & to get the reference
  $stdClass = Object::cast($stdClass, 'MyClass');
}
```

it fails on my remote server which is php 5.5.8 but the odd thing is it works on my local one (php 5.5.12).

what could be the trouble ? because the version of php is different ? or maybe php.ini has some directives disallowed on my remote machine ?

**ps** : also my local server is on windows and my remote one is on linux.

Comment: are you running the same operating system on your remote server as your local one?

Comment: @nomistic actually not. my remote is linux and my local is windows (sorry for that last one)

Comment: Not sure how answerable this is without sharing how you implemented `Object::cast`.  On the remote server, how does it 'fail'? Error? Wrong output?

Comment: @watcher I'm pretty sure nothing is related with the cast function since I also tried $stdClass = 1; but the variable gets persistent with its data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find where it didn't work, finally the problem is not really related to the question here, but since it was quite surprising I decide to answer myself here and maybe you can help me to explain what i just experienced because i am not sure to understand why.

I had two classes,

```
class Foo {
  ...
}

class Bar {

  /** @var Foo $foos */
  $foos = array();

  public function set_foos ($foos) { $this->foos = $foos; }
  public function get_foos () { return $this->foos; }
}
```

in Linux, writing

```
$foos = [new Foo(), new Foo()];
$bar = new Bar(); $bar->set_foos($foos);

foreach ($bar->get_foos as &$foo) {
  $foo = 1;
}
```

didn't work, the Foo Objects didn't get changed to 1. To change them to 1 I had to add a function to Bar class,

```
class Bar {

  ...

  public function serialize () {
    foreach($this->foos as &$foo) {
       $foo = 1; // works
    }
  }
}
```

can someone explain why ?

Comment: It could be a case-sensitivity issue. Things that work on Windows,which is generally not case-sensitive, may not work on Linux, which is.  Check your naming conventions.